# Input still existing when removed

Tags: javascript, html

i append a text input into form by using javascript, after i removed it by removeNode, it disappear, document.forms["form"].length = 0, but i can still get it's obj by using document.forms["form"]["inputname"] (not return null)

why?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are having trouble with firefox. In IE your code seems to work without any problem.

For removeNode to work in both IE and FF you can write like this

var objectToRemove = document.getElementByID ( "your object to remove" );

var parentNode = objectToRemove .parentNode;

parentNode.removeChild ( objectToRemove );

Hope this helps

Comment: I have tested it in both IE 7 and FF 3.0

Comment: FF 3.0, it can remove element (disappear) but element still in forms array

Answer (score 0):

anyway, you have to use document.getElementById() to correctly operate with elements tree. Constructions like document.forms[] is very old IE-oriented. But supported by some browsers for backward compatibility.